# what does "get a fist in your face" mean?

Tags: meaning

i heard it in a musical and the full sentence was "Keep it up, get a fist in your face". can anyone explain this to me? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Without a wider context it's impossible to be certain but generally getting "a fist in your face" means being punched in the face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, "a fist in your face" means "a punch in the face".

"Keep it up" means "Continue doing that".

The syntax is a form of the conditional, like "If x, then y".

> (If you) keep doing that, (the consequence will be, you) get a fist in your face.

It is a  threat (or a warning).

Comment: "It is a threat" ...  or a warning.

Comment: @GEdgar: +1. answer duly edited.